# Wordpress Apache Vhost Example

Tags: wordpress, installation

I'm trying to install wordpress but i'm confused as to how the Apache Vhost should look.

Ideally i'm after a vhost setup that adds additional security (make sure referrer is correct when doing comments)

I cant seem to find this anywhere (i'm not the best searcher)

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straight forward

from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=794248:

- create a new site(vhost) configuration at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ (replace  with whatever you want besides default) something like this should work

> ```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> DocumentRoot /path/to/new/site
> ServerName www.example.com
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- enable your new site

> ```
> sudo a2ensite <site name>
> ```

- restart apache to listen on your new port and load your new site

> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
> ```

Comment: Hi ALex, thanks for posting.  I've done the above and all works.  Do you now of any Security Gotchas i can add to the vhost to secure my blog a little more.  I'm thinking of comment spam and things like that

Comment: All of that is to be done in PHP already. The VHOST extension just provides the ability to host more domains on one server instance.
In PHP use anti-spam services like akismet, protect with captcha.

Answer (score 0):

This [guide for vhosts using mamp](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php) will help you with the setup! This saved me a lot of time.